# XBee ZDO active end point requests are not passed out to the UART when AO is set to 3

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I configured my [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) 2 modules using X-CTU, one as a router [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) and other as a coordinator API by setting AO to 3. But when I send ZDO active end point requests, it is not passed out to the UART on the router side. But for our application we want the requests to be passed to the UART so that the controller can handle the requests. I tried both XB24-ZB and XB24-SE, but the XBee itself is providing a response for ZDO requests.

When I used profile ID 0x0109, the ZDO requests are passed to the UART for both XB24-ZB and XB24-SE. But according to the data sheet, the profile ID must be set to 0 to send ZDO commands. But when I do that, the request is not passed out to the UART. I am using firmware version 23A7 for the XB24-ZB router API and 21A7 for the XB24-ZB coordinator API.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the bytes you're sending as part of the request, or the frame that you're sending to the XBee that contains the ZDO request?  You need to make sure the source and destination endpoints are 0 and that the profile ID is 0.

The `zigbee_walker` sample from https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library sends Active Endpoint Requests, and responds to them.  You might want to try using that code for your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply




Please check the packets, here source and destination endpoint is 0 and profile id is also 0

1) simple discriptor req send from router to cordinator =   7E 00 18 11 01 00 13 A2 00 40 8B 3D 3E 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 E6 07
2) simple discriptor req send from coordinator to router = 7E 00 18 11 01 00 13 A2 00 40 A2 42 BD 4D F4 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 4D F4 E6 EA

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you.  Since you're requesting endpoint 0xE6, the XBee module will probably handle that itself instead of passing it through.  Try an "active endpoints" request and then send a simple descriptor request for an endpoint other than 0xE6.  Also, the network address in your second request (coordinator to router) needs to end with `F4 4D E6 EA`.  Inside the ZDO request, the network address is little endian, but in the XBee header it's big endian.  What do your Active Endpoint requests look like, and are they coming out on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in datasheet, XBEE handles supported ZDO requests itself when AO=3, and only pass non-supported ones to UART. you should set AO=1 to pass all ZDO requests to UART